# Google Chrome won't refresh in vino on Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: google-chrome, macosx, remote-access, vino

Client: Max OS X remote desktop on Yosemite 10.10.3
Server: Vino (Desktop Access) on Ubuntu 14.4 running in a parallels VM on ANOTHER Mac

It took a while to get all this to work and I followed all the hints I could find online, even using flashback to set Metacity as my WM, because with Unity nothing refreshed.

But Google Chrome displays the same problem Unity does: it does not refresh at all on the client side. In fact, when you open Chrome, the window doesn't even render at all on the client (although I can see it's there when I look at the Parallels window on the remote Mac.

I tried shutting off some animations in Compiz configuration and even used dconf editor to set Metacity to reduce functionality but to no avail.

Anyone else run into this problem and come up with a solution? TIA

PS If anyone is wondering what the motivation is behind this setup: I have a decked out 16GB headless Mac Mini which I use as a VM server for testing all kinds of stuff in VMs. For the most part windowless Ubuntu servers do the trick but for some things I want to test on an Ubuntu desktop. I access all these and do all my work on my laptop. I could run the Ubuntu desktop on my laptop but I'd rather not waste the memory. I can also remote desktop to the Mac and full screen the Ubuntu desktop, but it looks better as a direct VNC client.